# Ground based path generation from RGBD camera

Tags: kinematics, dynamics, stereo-vision, path-planning

How does one generate a trajectory for a ground vehicle using an RGBD camera? For a drone it's simpler since you're not constrained by having to move on the ground but it's not clear to me how trajectory planning works if your movements limit you to moving on the ground plane.